# order status Pending Payment after payment(paypal) in magento

Tags: magento

I’m using Magento ver. 1.7.0.2.Order status is pending payment after paid via Paypal.

Comment: This is not a real question. As per the guidelines in the [faq], the best questions are about a real, actual programming problem you are facing. Please [edit] your post to improve it. Good luck!

Comment: what is the problem you rectify?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your Magento Installation doesn't block Paypal request. By me I found the following IP address which are the IP of the hosts which does this response:

```
173.0.82.126 Paypal
66.135.197.163 Paypal-developer
66.135.197.160 Paypal-sandbox
66.135.197.162 Paypal-sandbox
66.135.197.141 api-paypal-sandbox
66.135.197.164 api-sandbox-paypal
216.113.169.205 Paypal-sandbox
216.113.188.202 Paypal-notify
216.113.188.203 Paypal-notify
216.113.188.204 Paypal-notify
66.211.170.66 Paypal-notify
```

Comment: i set Transfer Cart Line Items=no still problem exists

Answer (score 0):

First run paypal in debug mode and check your error log.

If all setting from backend(Magento) are done right.,you should check your ipn value in paypal account. It is by default www.sitename.com/paypal/ipn in Magento

Change it to your required value in paypal or magento but it should match.

And then try making payment it should work.